# Session keep track of whose logged in and only show to members

Tags: codeigniter, session

I'm not really sure what to do when it comes to dealing with session.

After I log in and set a session data.

How do I keep private pages to only show to those who are logged in.

Do I have to run that kind of validation to all my views?

```
<?php

if($this->session->userdata('is_loggedin')!=1)
{
    redirect('KGindex/index','refresh');
}

?>
```

I'm not even sure if that is correct, right now it messed up my code. functions don't work anymore.

Where do I run session validations?

Answer (score 0):

You want to be doing this check **in your controller** rather than in the view.  For example

```
class Account extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        if($this->session->userdata('is_loggedin')!=1)
        {
            redirect('KGindex/index','refresh');
        }
    }
}
```

If you know that every function in your controller requires the user to be logged in then you could include the check in the `__construct()` function as this is called whenever the class is accessed.  Therefore you would only need the put the code in one place.

```
class Account extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        if($this->session->userdata('is_loggedin')!=1)
        {
            redirect('KGindex/index','refresh');
        }
    }

    public function index()
    {
        //__construct() has already been called
    }
}
```

Comment: But what if i manually input the url of the views? What then.

Btw when un setting a data, for example when i set a data, i added 'is_loggedin' => TRUE

when i unset should i set it to FALSE? or just ''

Comment: $this->session->userdata('is_loggedin') =>  Call to a member function userdata() on a non-object

Comment: All requests should go through a controller though.  User `$this->session->unset_userdata()` rather than setting it to `FALSE`.  If you are getting that error it means the session library hasn't been loaded.